# Copy Route information to Works order route

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to copy multiple lines from a Route, `Table: Route` to the Route of a Works Order, `Table: ProdRoute`

I am trying the following code, which is not working:

```
    static void CopyRoute(Args _args)
{

ProdRoute        prodRoute;
Route            route;
ProdTable        prodTable;
;



ttsBegin;


INSERT_RECORDSET prodRoute
    (
    OprNum,
    OprPriority,
    OprId,
    OprNumNext
    )
Select
    OprNum,
    OprPriority,
    OprId,
    OprNumNext
from
    route
join prodTable
where prodRoute.ProdId == prodTable.ProdId &&
prodTable.RouteId == route.RouteId;

ttsCommit;

    info("Copy finished!");
}
```

This is the route itself:

[image]

And I want to copy the data between the red lines into the route of the works order:

[image]

As you can see in my Job, which isn't working, I want to accomplish this by joining the `ProdTable` itself, based on the `RouteId` on the `ProdTable`, I want to copy the lines from Route (which matches the `RouteId`). Then fill this data into the `ProdRoute` table of the Works Order.

I am not sure what step to take so I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data structures around routes is too complex to achieve what you want with a single `insert_recordset` statement. To get started, you should look into the data structures of route, specifically tables `RouteTable`, `RouteVersion`, `Route` and `RouteOpr` and how they relate to each other. The biggest eye opener for me was when I realized that the lines of a route are not kept in one table `Route`, but the data is distributed between tables `Route` and `RouteOpr` and that one `RouteOpr` record can relate to more than one `Route` record.

After you got a feel for the data structures, I recommend taking a look at class `ProdUpdCostEstimation` and its method `createProdRoute`, which shows one example how standard functionality creates a production route from a route.